# How to optimize for speed a sql multiple select with SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, sum

I have a really long select from my database with many joins. The problem is with counting SUM: without sum, select time is about 3s, but with SUM is about 15s.

Is it possible to optimize my select to obtain a shorter select time?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
    accomodation.id, 
    accomodation.aid, 
    accomodation.title_en, 
    accomodation.title_url_en, 
    accomodation.address, 
    accomodation.zip, 
    accomodation.stars, 
    accomodation.picture, 
    accomodation.valid_from, 
    accomodation.valid_to, 
    accomodation.latitude, 
    accomodation.longitude, 
    accomodation.city_id AS 
    accomodation_city_id, 
    db_cities.id AS city_id, 
    db_cities.title_en AS city, 
    db_cities.title_url AS city_url, 
    db_countries.title_en AS country_title, 
    db_countries.title_url_en AS country_url, 
    accomodation_type.class AS accomodation_type_class, 
    accomodation_review_value_total.value AS review_total, 
    MIN(accomodation_price.price) AS price_from, 
    accomodation_rooms.total_persons 

FROM 
    (SELECT aid, MAX(info_date_add) AS max_info_date_add FROM accomodation GROUP BY aid) accomodation_max 

INNER JOIN accomodation 
    ON 
        accomodation_max.aid = accomodation.aid AND 
        accomodation_max.max_info_date_add = accomodation.info_date_add 

LEFT JOIN db_cities 
    ON ( 
        db_cities.id = accomodation.city_id OR 
        (((acos(sin((db_cities.latitude*pi()/180)) * sin((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) + cos((db_cities.latitude*pi()/180)) * cos((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) * cos(((db_cities.longitude - accomodation.longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) < '20') 

JOIN db_countries 
    ON db_countries.id = accomodation.country_id 

LEFT JOIN accomodation_review_value_total 
    ON accomodation_review_value_total.accomodation_aid = accomodation.aid 

LEFT JOIN accomodation_type_value 
    ON accomodation_type_value.accomodation_id = accomodation.id 

LEFT JOIN accomodation_type 
    ON accomodation_type.id = accomodation_type_value.accomodation_type_id 

JOIN accomodation_season 
    ON ( 
        accomodation_season.accomodation_aid = accomodation.aid AND 
        ( '2013-11-04' BETWEEN accomodation_season.start_date AND accomodation_season.end_date OR '2013-11-05' BETWEEN accomodation_season.start_date AND accomodation_season.end_date ) )

JOIN accomodation_price 
    ON 
        accomodation_price.accomodation_aid = accomodation.aid AND 
        accomodation_price.accomodation_price_type_id = '1' AND 
        accomodation_price.accomodation_price_cat_id = '1' AND 
        accomodation_price.price BETWEEN '20' AND '250' AND 
        accomodation_price.accomodation_season_id = accomodation_season.id 

JOIN accomodation_theme_value 
    ON accomodation_theme_value.accomodation_id = accomodation.id 

INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        accomodation_id, 
        SUM(accomodation_rooms.rooms) AS total_rooms, 
        SUM(accomodation_rooms.beds * accomodation_rooms.rooms) AS total_persons 
    FROM accomodation_rooms 
    GROUP BY accomodation_id) accomodation_rooms 

    ON 
        accomodation_rooms.accomodation_id = accomodation.id AND 
        accomodation_rooms.total_persons >= '4' 

WHERE 
    db_countries.title_url_en LIKE '%spain%' AND 
    db_cities.title_url LIKE '%barcelona%' AND 
    accomodation_type_value.accomodation_type_id IN (5,10) AND 
    total_rooms >= '2' AND 
    accomodation_theme_value.accomodation_theme_id IN (11,12,13) AND 
    accomodation.stars IN (3,4,5) AND 
    ( accomodation_review_value_total.value >= '4.5' ) AND 
    db_cities.id = '2416' 

GROUP BY accomodation.aid 

ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN accomodation.valid_to>=NOW() AND accomodation.valid_from<=NOW() AND MIN(accomodation_price.price) IS NOT NULL THEN 0 
        WHEN NOW()>accomodation.valid_to AND accomodation.valid_to>'0000-00-00' AND MIN(accomodation_price.price) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
        WHEN accomodation.valid_to>=NOW() AND accomodation.valid_from<=NOW() THEN 2 
        WHEN NOW()>accomodation.valid_to AND accomodation.valid_to>'0000-00-00' THEN 3 
    ELSE 4 END, 
    review_total DESC, 
    accomodation.title_en 

LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Optimizations will depend on your DBMS and the execution plan of your query. Are you referring to the two SUMs in the sub-query (accomodation_rooms)?

Comment: I suggest that you post which DBMS you use and your execution plan (e.g., EXPLAIN PLAN). Without that it will be difficult to propose optimizations.

Comment: Ok i use MySQL database. What do you mean EXPLAIN PLAN?

Comment: You can use the [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/execution-plan-information.html) statement. You might tell from the plan whether you should create some indexes to speed up processing. You can also compare the two plans with and without the aggregation to understand the different execution.

Comment: You might want to see if you can move the sub queries in question to a WITH clause before the select to prevent the calculations from needing to be done multiple times.